# cross nested model R

Tags: mixed-model, nested-models

I need help to understand how to enter a nested factor in a model. Basically, I tested 38 Italians and 35 Persian asking them to decide whether a sentence was congruent or not with an action they watched beforehand. The action congruency and the action type (abstract or concrete) are within factors. In GLM it would be a simple repeated measures Anova in which you have as within factor action type (ConcAst) and Congruency(cog/incong), and as between factor the group. However, it is much more correct to use linear mixed model to control for variability in the materials and in the subjects that I entered as random factors. The point is that the materials are qualitatively different, so it is nested design, since the sentences used for Persian people are different compared to the sentences used for Italians. My question is how I have to code this in the script that I entered below. At the moment it says that the model does not converge. Is it correct to write ((1|Sentence:Subject) to indicate that sentences depend from the subjects? In my txt file I named subjects and materials with different names. Moreover, can you suggest to me a code to represent my data? The box plot is not clear enough, and exceed the margins.

> str(ItaPersRclean)
>   'data.frame':   4034 obs. of  6 variables:
>    $ Subject : int  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
>  $ Sentence: Factor w/ 25 levels " pick","accarezza",..: 2 2 2 2 2 3 3 3 3 3 ...
>    $ Congr   : Factor w/ 2 levels "cong","incong": 1 1 2 2 1 1 1 2 2 2 ...
>  $ ConcAst : Factor w/ 2 levels "abst","conc": 2 2 2 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
>    $ Acc     : int  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
>  $ RT      : int  1173 2177 1370 1220 1489 1348 2253 1500 1832 2214 ...
>        **script**
>       library(lme4)
>       library(lsmeans)
>       library(lmerTest)
>       ItaPersR = read.table("C:\Users\chiar\Downloads\ItaPersR.txt",  header=TRUE, sep="\t")

```
summary(ItaPersR)
head(ItaPersR,n=10)   #per vedere le prime 10 righe
tail(ItaPersR,n=10)   #per vedere le ultime 10 righe
ItaPersRclean<-subset(ItaPersR, ItaPersR$RT>0)
summary(ItaPersRclean)
str(ItaPersRclean)
     model1 <- lmer(RT ~ ConcAst+ Congr + ConcAst*Congr + (1|Subject)+ (1|Sentence), data=ItaPersRclean, REML = TRUE)
    anova(model1)
    model2 <- lmer(RT ~ ConcAst+ Congr +(1|Subject)+ (1|Sentence),   data=ItaPersRclean, REML = TRUE)
        anova(model1, model2)
    anova(model1,type="3",test="F")    
   lsmeans(model1,pairwise~ConcAst*Congr,adjust="tukey")#si fanno i post hoc
    boxplot(RT~Congr*ConcAst, data=ItaPersRclean, col="aquamarine", range=0, xlab="Congr", ylab="RTs", cex.axis=1.2)
```

Comment: Please don't add screenshots to show your code. You can paste the code directly  into the question and format with 4 leading spaces per line.. Regarding your problem, please also add some information about the number of sentences. It would be helpful if you can also add the output of `str(ItaPersRclean)` to the question.

Comment: Thanks Robert for editing

Comment: We don't help specifically with coding here, but I sense some substantive issues in the question we can address. First, I am confused if your design is crossed or nested. Nested means you ask each subject several questions, and they are all different. Some examples of nesting include you have (different) children nested in (for example) 10 classes, and your DV is the test score. Or you have different patients nested within 5 hospitals, and your DV is length of stay. Here, you don't have one patient observed in several hospitals.

Comment: If you had the same patient in several hospitals, or some children attend several of the classes during the year, then I believe that's a crossed design. Which do you have?

Comment: It s for sure nested